# comparing multi sheet and column data in VBA

Tags: vba

As a part of a bigger application i am trying to search a string in master data location{MATERIAL_REQUIREMENT_SHEET}( first column from bottom up). If the string(test3) is available then the the code should transfer data from the sheet (test3) to column 2 of master data.
Now, the problem i am facing is that if 'test3'   is not available in the master data, then my code should insert a row and  transfer data from sheet(test3). to do this i need to have some else statement with for loop. and am struck here.
are there any better alternatives than the for loop for this instance? Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub EE_MATDATA_TRANSFER_PR_Click()
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, test3 As String, var As Integer, bln As 
Boolean, activesheetlastrow As Integer
    Dim prdatalastrow As Integer

 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    test3 = Sheets(REF).Range("AA101").Value
    Sheets(test3).Activate
    activesheetlastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MATERIAL_REQUIREMENT_SHEET.Activate
    prdatalastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 '--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        For j = prdatalastrow To 2 Step -1
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1) = test3 Then
                For k = 37 To activesheetlastrow

                    var = Application.Match(Cells(j, 2).Value, Sheets(test3).Cells(k, 1), 0)
                    If Not IsError(var) Then
                        Sheets(test3).Cells(k, 7).Copy
                        Sheets(MATERIAL_REQUIREMENT_SHEET).Cells(j, 6).Paste
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
       ?? What to do if NULL??
 '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Sub
```

Comment: You have not stated your problem yet. Why are you stuck? Why can't you add a `for` loop in the `else` statement? What kind of data do you want to transfer? How should it look at the end? It might help to create a minimal example that exactly showcases your problem.

Comment: my question is can i use else with for statement?

Comment: Sure you can! Just put the **whole** `If - else - end if` statement into the `for` loop. Have you tried it? Did you get an error? If yes, what kind of error? Update your question with this information.

Comment: @DavidG as listed ihave a if-else-endif in for loop already. what i wanted to know is what to do if a for loop results in null data.

Comment: i will try to explain what i am trying to do here

Comment: In workbook i have a master data sheet(MATERIAL_REQUIREMENT_SHEET)  into which i want to import data from other working work sheets named after their project numbers(test3). in the master data sheet i have three columns, Project name, ItemID and requirement. now, from the above code i intended to first compare whether the project exists in the masted data sheet ( the for loop). then if it exists then, whether itemid is already entered if so then copy itemID requirements. Now, my problem is what if the project is new. then i won't have a Project no entered in master data.

Comment: that is the "else" for the for loop which i am looking for.

Comment: i have corrected the code

Comment: What do you mean with "if NULL"? An error message? If "var" is NULL?

Comment: null means there is no return from the "FOR " loop.

Comment: means the var am matching with ( If ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1) = test3 Then)

Comment: A loop never returns anything, functions do. Just add an `If` statement to your loop to check for the `NULL` case. Updated my answer below accordingly.

Comment: @DavidG you are missing my point. what if the statement, **ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1)** is not equal to test3 ? to know this the loop has to go through all the columns of first row (**all "j" values**). how to include this in my coding?

Comment: It seems that your problem is on a conceptual level and not (yet) actually a coding problem. Can you update your question with a numbered list (not a text) with bullet points of your desired steps? I updated my answer accordingly with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop only contains one half of your if statement.

Move this line

```
Next j
```

after the

```
End If
```

statement.

Edit: Here for your adjusted code

```
Private Sub EE_MATDATA_TRANSFER_PR_Click()
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, test3 As String, var As Integer, bln As 
Boolean, activesheetlastrow As Integer
    Dim prdatalastrow As Integer

    test3 = Sheets(REF).Range("AA101").Value
    Sheets(test3).Activate
    activesheetlastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MATERIAL_REQUIREMENT_SHEET.Activate
    prdatalastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = prdatalastrow To 2 Step -1
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1) = test3 Then
                For k = 37 To activesheetlastrow

                    var = Application.Match(Cells(j, 2).Value, Sheets(test3).Cells(k, 1), 0)
                    If Not IsError(var) Then
                        Sheets(test3).Cells(k, 7).Copy
                        Sheets(MATERIAL_REQUIREMENT_SHEET).Cells(j, 6).Paste
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
            If test3 = NULL Then
                'code for the case of "var = NULL"
            End If
        Next j
End Sub
```

Avoid `ActiveSheet` statements, assign sheets to `worksheet` variables and use them instead.

**Update**

Make a list of the things your code should do, like this:

1. Start
2. check if value A is equal to B (if yes, go to 3, else go to 4)
3. Do action X
4. Do action Y
5. End

Making a small flow chart before writing those points might help as well.